# Compound formula without decimals for programming

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

I am trying to write a compound formula in a programming language that doesn't have decimal places.

For something that I thought was going to be simple... I seem to be struggling a bit...

Using Excel as a test area I have written;

```
1 * (1 + 0.0025) ^ 2212
```

Which equals $250.4$ (rounded).

I'm struggling to write this without the $0.0025$ (representing $0.25\% $). Is there a way I can multiply this equation out so that I don't have to use $0.0025$ to represent $0.25\% $?

For example, have $0.25\% $ represented as $25$?

I have tried;

```
1 * (1 + 25 / 10000) ^ 2212
```

and

```
10000 * (10000 + 25) ^ 22120000;
```

And these do not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "And these do not work."  Why not?  You can also do $25*10^{-4}$.   There's no reason the first won't work.  The second one is utterly absurd though.  (Although $10^{-4*2212}*(10025)^{2212}$ will.)

Comment: This is probably more of a question for stack overflow, as you are most likely having int overflows and/or errors with multi-precision arithmetic.

Comment: @fleablood The programming language does not support floating point numbers, so some suggestions were to multiply the numbers out to be larger, but yes, it is obviously pretty wrong.

Comment: @jman Yeah, thanks for the advice, I will try there

Comment: @MitchellNZ you could try python, their big integer library is built in by default and it's probably one of the easiest to use.  If you are stuck with a particular language you could google around to find libraries.  GMP for c++ is good and Java has BigInt built int.

Comment: @jman The language I am using is Solidity, and I can't really change since I need it for the Ethereum network.. Also, there aren't exactly many libraries for it! Thanks for the advice though!